# Custom posts visible in admin, but truncate in public

Tags: wp-query

I am trying to return some custom post types. When I view the page as the logged in admin, all the posts are displayed unpaginated as expected/desired. But when I view the page as a logged out user, the posts truncate at 10 results.

Using the following code:

```
                <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
                    'nopaging' => true, 
                    'posts_per_page' => 500, /*Purposely set high for debugging*/
                    'post_type' => 'parts', 
                    'category_name' => 'category-a',
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    'order' => 'ASC' ) 
                ); ?>
                
                ...loop html...

                <?php 
                    endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
```

**Confirmed:** All posts are published and public.

**Confirmed:** I noticed this truncation aligns with the "Blog pages show at most" setting in the Reading preferences. I changed that to 20 to test. This had no impact on either logged in (still displays all) or logged out (still displays 10) view.

**Researched:** pre_get_posts approach, but did not implement. Understanding this is a more technical change, I wanted to make sure I covered my basic troubleshooting before jumping into that.

It seems weird it displays correctly in admin, but not public.

Thanks for any advice.